# How to slow down a loop with setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, settimeout, setinterval

I have an array called RotatorNames. It contains random things but let's just say that it contains  `["rotatorA","rotatorB","rotatorC"]`.

I want to loop through the array, and for each item i want to trigger a click event. I have got some of this working, except that the everything get's triggered instantly. How can i force the loop to wait a few seconds before it continues looping.

Here's what i have.

```
function Rotator() {
    var RotatorNames = ["rotatorA","rotatorB","rotatorC"];
    RotatorNames.forEach(function(entry){
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            //Trigger that elements button.
            var elemntBtn = $('#btn_' + entry);
            elemntBtn.trigger('click');
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

You can run this to see what my issue is. http://jsfiddle.net/BxDtp/
Also, sometimes the alerts do A,C,B instead of A,B,C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm sure the other answers work, I would prefer using this setup:

```
function rotator(arr) {
    var iterator = function (index) {
        if (index >= arr.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        console.log(arr[index]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            iterator(++index);
        }, 1500);
    };

    iterator(0);
};

rotator(["rotatorA", "rotatorB", "rotatorC"]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BxDtp/4/

It just seems more logical to me than trying to get the iterations to line up correctly by passing the "correct" value to `setTimeout`.

This allows for the array to be continually iterated over, in order. If you want it to stop after going through it once, change `index = 0;` to `return;`.

Comment: Very nice, this actually reloops as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the timeout based on the current index:

```
RotatorNames.forEach(function(entry, i) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        //Trigger that elements button.
        var elemntBtn = $('#btn_' + entry);
        elemntBtn.trigger('click');
    }, 5000 + (i * 1000)); // wait for 5 seconds + 1 more per element
});
```

Comment: This works great, but for some reason the first array item get's repeated before it goes to B and C

Comment: i figured out why. It's because im starting the forloop at 0, and 0 is by default already shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var idx = 0;
function Rotator() {
    var RotatorNames = ["rotatorA", "rotatorB", "rotatorC"];
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(RotatorNames[idx]);
            idx = (idx<RotatorNames.length-1) ? idx+1:idx=0;
            Rotator();
        }, 5000);
}
Rotator();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BxDtp/3/)**

(note that I used `console.log` instead of `alert`)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do what you're after:

```
function Rotator(index){
  var RotatorNames = ["rotatorA","rotatorB","rotatorC"];
  index = (index === undefined ? 0 : index);

  var $btn = $("#btn_"+RotatorNames[index]);
  $btn.click();

  if(RotatorNames[index+1]!==undefined){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      Rotator(index+1);
    }, 500);
  }
}
```